# Javascript Class and scope

Tags: javascript, class, scope, indexeddb

I want to make a class in javascript to reuse from my main code in the connection with an indexeddb object. What I have now is:

```
function DATABASE() {
    this.DB_NAME = 'MYdatabase';
    this.DB_VERSION = 1;
    this.db = null;
    this.results = null;
}

DATABASE.prototype.open = function(callback) {
    var req = indexedDB.open(this.DB_NAME, this.DB_VERSION);

    req.onsuccess = function (evt) {
        this.db = this.result;
        callback();
    };

    req.onerror = function (evt) {
        console.error("openDb:", evt.target.errorCode);
    };

    req.onupgradeneeded = function (evt) {
        console.log("openDb.onupgradeneeded");        
    };
}
```

My problem here is that when the onsuccess executes I loose the scope of my main class and this is not what I expected. How can I do what I am looking for?
I want to make some connections at the same time with this, something like:

```
var DB = new DATABASE();
DB.open(function(res){});

var DB2 = new DATABASE();
DB2.open(function(res){});

var DB3 = new DATABASE();
DB3.open(function(res){});
```

thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Under `var req` add `var self = this;` and use like this whenever the scope changes:

```
self.db = self.result;
```

Answer (score 1):

> My problem here is that when the onsuccess executes I loose the scope of my main class and this is not what I expected.

It's not *scope*, but the value of `this` during a function call depends on how the function is called. So what's happening is that the functions you're assigning to `req` are getting called with `this` being a *different* value than it is in the call to `open`.

> How can I do what I am looking for?

Since your functions already close over the scope of the call to `open`, the easiest way is to do [what Andy suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19048568/157247):

```
DATABASE.prototype.open = function(callback) {
    var req = indexedDB.open(this.DB_NAME, this.DB_VERSION);
    var self = this;                                        // <=== New

    req.onsuccess = function (evt) {
        self.db = this.result;                              // <=== Changed
        callback();
    };

    // ...
}
```

Note: In the changed line, I don't know what `this.result` is, so I don't know whether to change `this` to `self` there as well. It's entirely possible that you actually want `this.result`, if `result` is a property of the object that `this` points to on the callback.

More:

- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)
- [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?  Putting the open function inside the DATABASE instead of on the prototype.

```
function DATABASE() {
  var _this=this;
  _this.DB_NAME = 'MYdatabase';
  _this.DB_VERSION = 1;
  _this.db = null;
  _this.results = null;

  _this.open = unction(callback) {
    var req = indexedDB.open(_this.DB_NAME, _this.DB_VERSION);

    req.onsuccess = function (evt) {
      _this.db = _this.result;
      callback();
    };

    req.onerror = function (evt) {
      console.error("openDb:", evt.target.errorCode);
    };

    req.onupgradeneeded = function (evt) {
      console.log("openDb.onupgradeneeded");        
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much to everyone, I think I am going to use the ChrisC method.
Again, thanks so much for this useful help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var that = this
req.onsuccess = function (evt) {
    that.db = that.result;
    callback();
};
```

Also I recommend to read this article: [Scope and this in JavaScript](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/)